# What version is the CKEditor in the CKEditor module?

Tags: wysiwyg

I have installed the [CKEditor](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor) module for Drupal 7 version 1.14. This version of the module comes with CKEditor already integrated with the module, so I am not sure how to find out exactly which version of the CKEditor this module comes with by default. I need to know this because when adding [plugins](http://ckeditor.com/addons/plugins/all) from the CKEditor website only certain versions of the plugin are compatible with certain versions of the CKEditor. So how can I find this out? I have looked through the different module and JS files but I cannot find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library files are linked to directly via CKEditor's own CDN, so the answer can change depending on what their CDN is currently serving.

You can use `ckeditor_get_version()` to check which version is currently being used:

```
$current_version = ckeditor_get_version();
// e.g. 4.3.2
```

Comment: Ok sure. I'm not much of a developer, so where would I place the ckeditor_get_version() function?

Comment: Sorry that was too simplistic - you can specify which version to use at `/admin/config/content/ckeditor/editg`  (whether that's a specific version via the CDN, or a specific version you've downloaded to the libraries folder)

Answer (score 3):

In your browser with an open Drupal site:

- press the F12 key to open the console (or right click anywhere on the page and select "inspect")
- select "console" tab if not already selected
- type this command and press enter: `CKEDITOR.version`

Comment: Add this code on browser console where the editor is visible.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find it in the status report (/admin/reports/status) on my drupal 7.58 site:

[image]

Comment: This is not on d8+ anymore

Answer (score -1):

You can go to Ckeditor module in your contrib module list and open the readme.txt file. At the section "Requirement" you can see the compatible version of ckeditor library that you can download. the section look like this :

```
Requirements
------------
  - Drupal 7.x,
  - PHP 5.2 or greater,
  - CKEditor 3.4 or greater.
    You will need to download CKEditor from the official download site: http://ckeditor.com/download.
    It is recommended to always use the latest CKEditor version available.
```

Comment: But this doesn't tell me what exact version is installed with the plugin.

Comment: If you have already all the library in the directory ckeditor/ckeditor of the module, you can open the file "readme.md" at the top of this file, you have your version for ckeditor like this:

CKEditor 4
==========